# Recursive functions vs recursive lambdas in Haskell

Tags: haskell, fixpoint-combinators

I am a bit confused. There is no problem with defining ordinary recursive functions in Haskell. At the same time there is the standard `fix` function for defining recursive lambdas via fixed points. But besides being less readable a recursive lambda defined like that has an application overhead compared to a regular recursive functions that call themselves directly. So where would I practically need recursive lambdas and `fix`?

Answer (score 8):

You never need it. Sometimes it's mildly convenient, though.

```
foo = do
    foo1
    x <- foo2
    let loop = do
       y <- bar x
       if pred y then loop else return y
    z <- loop
    foo3 z
```

vs

```
foo = do
    foo1
    x <- foo2
    z <- fix $ \loop -> do
       y <- bar x
       if pred y then loop else return y
    foo3 z
```

I find the second to bit a bit less cumbersome. It's a minor thing, but I think it makes weird (ie, more complicated than that example, less likely to be something that exists in a library already) monadic looping look enough better that it's worth it to me to use that idiom. I also do like that it avoids binding another name into the context of the `do` block.